# Nuget gone crazy?

Tags: jenkins, nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package via jenkins.

It's a parameterized build that uses the following command to build the package:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\nuget.exe" pack "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Common.Extensions\Common.Extensions.csproj" -Properties Configuration=Release -Version 1.2.3 -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

Unfortunately this errors out with an "Invalid arguments" error.

I could not find any argument errors so I started removing options one at a time from the end.  Once I removed the 'IncludeReferencedProjects' and 'Version' options, the nuget package builds just fine.

Here is the strange part, I then re-introduced the options one at a time (not by re-typing them, just by going back in my command history and re-running previously failed commands) and the nuget packages build fine.

I am at my wits end.  How can a command fail the first time it receives a command only to later succeed with the same command?

I am using nuget 3.4.4

**EDIT**

Actually I was wrong about the sequence of events.  If I remove the last two options, it starts working.  If I then retype the version parameter, it works.  If I navigate up in history and run the exact same command (I used notepad++ compare tool to ensure I was running the same command) taken from command history it doesn't work.  The two commands are identical!  How can one work and the other not work?

**Edit 2**

I'm adding a screen shot below because this is so strange I think I must be missing something obvious:

[image]

The first command is hand typed.  As you can see it works.  The second command is taken from the clipboard from the 'console output' from jenkins and it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for the sanity of future developers here's what turned out to be the problem: character encoding!

The only thing I could think of that could explain this was that some character must LOOK like a valid character to me, but is not in fact ascii.

So I found a plugin for notepad++ called TextFX which has a way of converting text to Hex-16.  So I took the command that didn't work, pasted it into a new file and then pasted the hand typed version that did work and converted both to Hex-16.

Turns out that the hyphen '-' character was not a standard ascii hyphen.  I copied the options from somewhere on the net that must have been using a unicode encoding and they picked some weird hyphen look-alike instead of using the regular hyphen.

After re-entering the hyphens as standard ascii ones, my jenkins build returned to a functional state.